# Laravel 5.2 form validation call back function with ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to do a call back in form validation. 
But i can not access the

> $request['beginningDate']

inside

> $validator->after(function($validator) {

it returns **Undefined variable: request**

```
function store(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'beginningDate' => 'required|date|before:endingDate',
        'endingDate' => 'required|date|after:beginningDate',
    ]);

    $validator->after(function($validator) {
        $beginningDate = $request['beginningDate'];
        $endingDate = $request['endingDate'];
        $beginningDate = 'a';
        if ($beginningDate != '2015-02-01') {
            $validator->errors()->add('fendingDateield', 'Something is wrong with this field!');
        }
    });

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode(array( 'success' => true, 'errors' => null ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `use()` to insert your `$request` variable  along with your query.

```
 $validator->after(function($validator) use($request) {
        $beginningDate = $request['beginningDate'];
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine.
But could not understand what exactly the syntax refer 
**function($validator) use($request)**

Comment: @NSK It is because the closures have their own local scope they dont see outer variables.

Comment: One again thank you.when i am googling this error i couldn't get a single result to solve the problem, even in http://laravel.io/. i think,i have to do lots of home works.
please suggest me to refer some tutorials for doing right coding in laravel.

Comment: @NSK I don't know much about tutorials. Laravel documentation covered almost everything.

Comment: Ok Thank you @Sanzeeb Aryal